# How to create a Leaderboard from a file in python

Tags: python

This is my code from the beginning to the top, I'd like someone to tell me the next steps I need to take to create a file that can store the highest scores from the game. Basically I need the highest score to be taken and ordered into the leaderboard file, this means I need scores added, removed and sorted into the file. The two files I have can be seen in the image below -

````
   ``` #This allows for my program to have pre-defined functions.
import time
import random
i = 0
Player1Points = 0
Player2Points = 0
Player1Tiebreaker = 0
Player2Tiebreaker = 0
WinnersPoints = 0
#Allows the user to enter their profile details.
x = 1
#Creating the loop until the details are entered correctly.
while x == 1:
    Username1 = str(input("\nPlease enter your Username for player 1: "))
    Password1 = str(input("\nPlease enter your Password for player 1: "))
    Username2 = str(input("\nPlease enter your Username for player 2: "))
    Password2 = str(input("\nPlease enter your Password for player 2: "))
    #Validates the given infomation
    if Username1 == ("User1"):
        if Password1 == ("Password1"):
            print("\nWelcome User1, you are verified and may begin!")
    if Username2 == ("User2"):
        if Password2 == ("Password2"):
            print("\nWelcome User2, you are verified and may begin!")
            #Updates the loop to stop, becuase the correct information was entered.
            x += 1
    #If the details are incorrect, the user must retry.
    else:
        print(
            "\nSorry, but you are not verified to use this program. Please try again!"
        )
        #The program's loop will continue until details are entered correctly.
        x = 1
#Preperation for the dice game.
print("\nThe game shall begin in 3 seconds!")
time.sleep(1)
print("\n3")
time.sleep(1)
print("\n2")
time.sleep(1)
print("\n1")
time.sleep(1)
print("\nThe game has begun, User1 rolls first.")


#Dice rolling definition code.
def roll():
    die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    change = 10 if (die1 + die2) % 2 == 0 else -5
    points = die1 + die2 + change
    if die1 == die2:
        points += random.randint(1, 6)
    return points

for i in range(0,5):
    Player1Points += roll()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print("\nThe total score for ",Username1, "is:",Player1Points," Points")
    print("\nRolling...")
    Player2Points += roll()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print("\nThe total score for ",Username2, "is:",Player2Points," Points")
    print("\nRolling...")
    
#Tiebreaker code is from Stack Overflow from a user named "Amir A. Shabani".
if Player1Points == Player2Points:
    while Player1Tiebreaker == Player2Tiebreaker:


        Player1Tiebreaker = random.randint(1,6)
        Player2Tiebreaker = random.randint(1,6)

    if Player1Tiebreaker > Player2Tiebreaker:
        Player2Points = 0
    elif Player2Tiebreaker > Player1Tiebreaker:
        Player1Points = 0
#This code declares the winner.
if Player1Points > Player2Points:
    WinnersPoints = Player1Points
    winner_User = Username1
    winner = (WinnersPoints, Username1)
elif Player2Points > Player1Points:
    WinnersPoints = Player2Points
    winner = (WinnersPoints, Username2)
    winner_User = Username2
#This is where the code stops from "Amir A. Shabani".
print('\nCongrats,', winner_User,'you won with',WinnersPoints,'Points')
#Uploads data to a file.
if Player1Points < Player2Points:
    with open('scores.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write("Total Score For Player 2 is:" + str(Player2Points)+ ("\n"))
            f.close
else: Player1Points > Player2Points
with open('scores.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write("Total Score For Player 1 is:" + str(Player1Points)+ ("\n"))
            f.close
#Displays the leaderboard file data.
f = open('leaderboard.txt', 'r')
file_contents = f.read()
print (file_contents)
f.close()```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe save a text file like that:

"leaderboard = [['username1', 1996, 12.8], ['username2', 3245, 13.9], ['username3', 1228, 11.9]]

and use command:

exec(open('path/to/this/file.txt').read())
will make a variable of leaderboard.

to save the changed version of leaderboard, use:

file = open('path/to/your/file.txt', 'w')
file.write(str(leaderboard.append([player.name, player.score, player.time]))

That will work.

Comment: instead: if Boolean1: if Boolean2:, You can write: if Boolean1 and Boolean2:

Comment: the code doesn't work better, but it's more readable